# How does a single process handle multiple shared libraries linked to the same library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Multiple shared libraries linked to same library in Single process.

Lets assume I have libapp , libapp1 , libapp2 and Mainapp.
libapp1 is linked to libapp , libapp2 is linked to libapp.Main app linked to libapp1 and libapp2.
If there are global variable in libapp would it have two copies or a single copy ?
When Mainapp executes what would be the behavior of global variables ?

I see there is only one copy of global variables for one process Is my understanding correct ?
One definition Rule for single process ? How to solve this problem if we have libraries calling the same api with different parameters ?

Comment: This has very little to do with C or C++. What you call "global variables" are just symbols to the dynamic linker. What do you mean by "calling the same api with different parameters"?

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, library dependencies are encoded into executable files and libraries as DT_NEEDED entries. You can query those with the `ldd` command:

```
$ ldd /bin/sed
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffee2c69000)
        libacl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f0a806c6000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f0a8049e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0a802dd000)
        libattr.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f0a802d5000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f0a80261000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0a8025c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0a806fe000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0a80239000)
```

Each line lists the dependency and the actual location where this was found.
By default the dynamic linker (ld.so) queries a file called /etc/ld.so.conf for a list of paths where to look, but this process can be changed by either the binary itself (DT_RUNPATH entries) or the environment (LD_LIBRARY_PATH). See the ld.so manpage for information on both.

On Linux, the dynamic linker ensures that only a single copy of a specific *library file* is loaded into memory per process.
Thus, if a second library in a process has a DT_NEEDED entry for the same library file it will not load the file again.

Secondly, note that the dependencies are not just called "libfoo.so", but for example libpcre.so.**3**. This number is a way of versioning libraries. So one process could perfectly have a `libpcre.so.2` loaded alongside `libpcre.so.3`.
This is one way of solving ABI incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

part of the question is:
"I see there is only one copy of global variables for one process Is my understanding correct ?"

That is partly true.  in a working process there is one and only one instance of a global object.  but you have to look at the scope.  you use 'external' to tell the linker this object is found outside the module.  globals by default have the scope of the module they appear in.  when you link your link will fail if there are multiple declarations of globals with the same name.

IMO its bad practice to link several versions of a library into the same process.  you are better off to do the work you need to do to get it done with ONE of the versions of the shared library.

If you MUST link in several versions of the same shared library, hide all the calls inside a wrapper so that you can clearly mark where the different versions come into play.  that way YOUR process only interacts with the one and only one wrapper, which deals with the multiple versions of the shared library.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problems with a Windows program many years ago which used a combination of static libraries and dynamic link libraries (DLLs).  Some of the static libraries tried to create singletons in the classic fashion, by using a static variable.  But if more than one DLL linked the static library, each DLL would get its own copy of the static variable and the singleton wouldn't be so single anymore.

The solution was to create a DLL which was in charge of creating and disseminating singletons so that the static variables would only exist in one place.